# Please check out my code incrementer

Tags: javascript, html, security

I recently developed code that can run as a function parameter but I'm not quite sure how vulnerable it is to hacks and/or cheats.

Also, is there anything I could improve?

```js
const h1 = document.getElementById('hi')

world = "world";

function testCode(codeEntered) {
    var code = codeEntered;
  var run = code *= 1;
  return(run);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testCode(h1.textContent = world)">
Test
</button>

<h1 id="hi">
Hello
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Writing `testCode(h1.textContent = world)` is a bit unconventional, and might not do what you expect: this is the same as writing the two lines

  ```js
  h1.textContent = world;
  testCode(world);
  ```

  because the assignment (the first line) [evaluates to the value of the right hand side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment).
- Instead of writing `var code = codeEntered;`, you can save yourself a line and just use the variable `codeEntered` instead of making a new variable.
- The line  `var run = code *= 1;` also is a bit unexpected. This is equivalent to writing

  ```js
  code = code * 1;
  var run = code;
  ```

  But `code` is a string, and multiplying it by `1` evaluates to [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (try it!), so after that line, `code == run == NaN`.
- Code style: `return(run);` would typically be written `return run;` instead (it's not a function).
- In summary, `testCode` actually always returns `NaN`, but the value then gets thrown away because it isn't used anywhere. In effect, your code actually just runs `h1.textContent = world` when you click the button, then runs `testCode` whose value isn't used (but is always NaN anyway).

I hope this gives you some useful feedback.

Comment: I never really realized that, a while back I looked up a way to convert Numbers as strings into floating-point numbers and I thought that it would work the other way around.